# TFS - Branching Strategy vs or Changeset Strategy

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tfs

I have a debate going on in my team right now. Basically, there is the proposal to use Branching Strategy however, there are those who argue that the current setup, managing feature changes at the ChangeSet level, is the best way forward. This led me to trying to understand what the differences between Changesets and Branches. Are there really advantages of using the one over the other? Which of these is TFS optimized for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Changesets complement branches, a change set represents an arbitrary grouping of files defined by the developer branches can be used for two purposes:

- separate branches for QA and Release
- feature branches which touch multiple parts of a project where the end goal is to merge back into the main development effort

Track Changesets by associating them with work items and use branches to isolate larger units of work.

To get the best use out of TFS use both. See the branching and merging guide here 
http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/releases